# Nullpointer exception when trying to reference a session variable in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I have set a session variable in one servlet and am now tring to reference it later on. I can reference the session variable in the .jsp the first servlet redirects to but I get a null pointer exception when trying to reference it later on.

Here is where I define the session variable:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
ArrayList<Account> accountList = loginController.getAccounts(user);
session.setAttribute("accountsList", accountList);
```

At the moment it is just an arraylist of accounts with a single account object in it. I can access this account from the .jsp that this servlet redirects to.

However that .jsp then has links to further servlets which also use the accountlist.

```
if (session.getAttribute("accountsList") instanceof ArrayList && session.getAttribute("accountsList") != null) {
    log.debug("===============================================:The account list isn't null");
    ArrayList<Account> accountList = (ArrayList<Account>) session.getAttribute("accountsList");
    for (Account temp : accountList) {
        if (accountNum == temp.getAccountNumber()) {
            account = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in one of such servlets and when ran it fails on the start of the for loop. The log statement is printed to the tomcat console and then the following error is shown:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       com.fdmgroup.holla.servlet.StatementServlet.doGet(StatementServlet.java:54)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

line 54 is the for loop definition. I have a similar error with the other servlets. What do you think is going wrong as I can go into tomcat session admin and see that the accountslist isn't null, so I'm not really sure what is happening.

Comment: Can you log size of the list ?

Comment: I have just tried accountslist.size() and it came back with the same exception but now pointing at the line with accountslist.size().

Comment: No `<%@ page session="false"` and int the same sessions (session ID)? (Account should be Serializable but that can#t be it.) Log a bit.

Comment: Can you flip the conditions is `if` ?? it seems the `session.getAttribute("accountsList")` is null.

Comment: And also, instead of session, set `accountsList` to `request.setAttribute()` and try

Comment: I have changed the condition in the if statement to be `req.getAttribute("accountsList") != null && req.getAttribute("accountsList") instanceof ArrayList` and changed accountslist to be a request variable rather than a session variable but now the if is failing because the log statements are never passed. I have checked the sessions and I only have a single session in the system at any one time atm so I think it must be in the same session.

Comment: It worked after I changed the variable back to a session variable. Thanks all.